# JavaScript - click multiple buttons every second

Tags: javascript, html

These two buttons (star and remove) are in one div `<div class="rank_icon">` every button has another class for each user. The only thing that is the same is title and src of "remove" image.

[image: image with buttons]

Screenshot of HTML code: [html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw9R4.png)

I want to make JavaScript that clicks remove button for every user.

I have tried the following without success:

```
setInterval(function () {
  document.getElementByName("img").click();
}, 1);
```

Comment: Star and remove buttons have the same class: `class="officerIcon manageMemberAction"`

Comment: Show the actual HTML from the screenshot, not the screenshot.  Javascript works on the DOM hierarchy and a screen shot doesn't help us understand how to find the right objects in the DOM.

Comment: Okay I'll do my best :)

Comment: It looks like what youre looking for is more like $('.ran_icon').click(), than setInterval case, unless you want to click one button many times

Comment: I want to click the same button for another users -  like thousands of times (that much users).

Comment: I added screenshot of html code.

Comment: and why you cannot simply add the html code? jsfiddle at best
+ what doesnt work in your code, did you try to debug it?

Comment: Last question: Is there any way to make auto-accept alerts from website?

Comment: Okay I did it :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assumpe that inside you have the `remove` simply be a single element with a class called `class="remove"`. So then you can cycle through your class and do `click` on each `remove` class:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("rank_icon");
for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++)
{
    buttons[i].getElementsByClassName("remove")[0].click();
}
```

Below is an example Snippet with the structure:

```
<div class="rank_icon">
    ...
    <button class="remove" ... >X</button>
</div>

<div class="rank_icon">
    ...
    <button class="remove" ... >X</button>
</div>
```

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("rank_icon");
for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++)
{
    buttons[i].getElementsByClassName("remove")[0].click();
}
```

```html
<div class="rank_icon">
    <button class="remove" onclick="alert('t')">X</button>
</div>
    
<div class="rank_icon">
    <button class="remove" onclick="alert('t')">X</button>
</div>
```

Comment: what about $('.ran_icon .remove').click()? :) seems easier to me...

Comment: @mikus They aren't using jQuery. But yes it would be eaiser if they did.

Comment: @mikus Because OP doesn't say anything about jQuery

Comment: No, that is not that easy as you thought Spencer.

Comment: @TomaszTargiel You can apply the same concept to your problem, in your case looks like you want to use `..ClassName("officerIcon")[1]` assuming the structure is the same. [For example](http://jsfiddle.net/h5sw45mg/1/).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I know it should work - and it is but people aren't removed at all :/

Comment: Okay I did a few changes and it is working but steam allows me to remove only 3 people in one round > then refresh of the site > another 3 people > refresh > etc. > etc.